# I seriously messed up my explorer.exe

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I was trying to change my Windows Explorer appearance using some things like [this](http://seahorsepip.deviantart.com/art/Token-ExplorerFrame-Beta-3-155371375).  This involves replacing system files such as explorer.exe and explorerframe.dll. When I was installing one theme I messed up somehow and disabled dwm.exe (the theme apparently required it). I just ignored the problem and started using the basic windows 7 theme instead (no transparency). Today I tried switching it to the Windows 98 style theme, and that made it so Windows explorer crashes when I try to start it up (except for the taskbar). I can't switch it back because I can't open explorer...is there some way that I can reset those files that are messed up? Thanks

Comment: Did you try a System Restore to go back to before you did that?

Comment: @techie007 No, I didn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hit <kbd>win</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> , then use that then use that to run `cmd.exe`.

You then can use [sfc /scannow](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833) (with a install cd, or file caches on the system itself - if you have a i386 folder) to restore the default files.

Comment: I managed to get explorer and my taskbar working now using that...however, Windows Aero seems to still be disabled.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/28685/how-to-re-enable-aero-effects-in-windows-7-after-it-has-crashed see this

Comment: Still doesn't work, when I try an Aero theme I just get the basic Windows theme.