# Alternative ways of running commands on remote machine

Tags: windows-7, rpc

I can `net use \\COMPUTERNAME\IPC$ /user:COMPUTERNAME\ADMIN ACCOUNT` successfully to a Windows 7 machine where the Window Manager has crashed, but unfortunatley get a `System error 5 has occurred` & `Access is denied` when using `psexec \\COMPUTERNAME -u ADMIN ACCOUNT -c cmd`.

I presume this is because I hadn't configured Windows Firewall to allow this sort of access (I forget what rule needs to be adjusted), right?

Is there any other vector I could explore to just try and run `net start uxsms` (From [How to re-enable aero effects in Windows 7 after it has crashed?](https://superuser.com/questions/28685/#28686)) on the remote PC?

Comment: add the "-h" parameter to the command line to elevate the command.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @magicandre1981 - However, I still get `Access is denied` when using `psexec \\COMPUTERNAME -u ADMIN ACCOUNT -c -h cmd`

Answer (score 1):

PSexec use SMB protocol, so you should try enable rule for TCP 445 port in firewall. Also i think psexec require write access to ADMIN$ share on target computer.

Comment: Would this be TCP 445 in firewall of machine I am using to try and connect to target, or both (Noting that I cannot access anything on the target PC with local peripherals)? Also, `net use \\COMPUTERNAME\ADMIN$ /user:COMPUTERNAME\ADMIN ACCOUNT` also gives me `System error 5 has occurred` & `Access is denied`

Comment: You should open 445 TCP inbound port on destination machine. Outbound ports are open in windows firewall by default. Admin$ share is actualy just `C:\windows` folder. Try also supply `PSExec -p` parameter with password to admin account.

Comment: But I cannot access the GUI on the destionation machine... Also, `psexec` prompts for password if not supplied explictly as an argument.

Comment: If account you use for connecting has administative rights on the destination machine, try `-s` argument. It will run psexec with system privileges.