# Can i create shortcuts to turn on/off windows 7 aero function?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, aero

According to my question heading, is it possible to create desktop shortcuts to turn on/off `Windows AERO` ? If yes how can i do it ?

Comment: use [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/28686/270195)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, create two batch files containing one of the below sections in each. Technically its not a shortcut but it should work fine and simplistically. If it really *must* be a shortcut you can store the batch files elsewhere and make shortcuts to them i suppose. You can also run the command directly from a command prompt by typing them in manually, you don't need the @Echo Off part if you do. Whichever way you decide to run to the command, you need to make sure you have the proper access to change the service state (ie admin rights). So do it from a elevated command or by right clicking the batch file and selecting run as administrator.

```
@ECHO OFF  
NET >NUL stop uxsms
```

and

```
@ECHO OFF  
NET >NUL start uxsms
```