# Return to Aero screen effects after VNC usage?

Tags: windows-10, aero, ultravnc

After a VNC session (UltraVNC 1.2.1.2) with my Windows 10 PC (what I believe caused the problem), dragging windows on the screen with my mouse results in only rectangles being moved, instead of the full contents of the window, as it normally does.  Is there a way to restore the full Aero-effects functionality without logging out/rebooting?

Comment: Just as a hunch, have you tried pressing `F5` to refresh your desktop?

Comment: @CheesusCrust thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't work.

Comment: Which fork/version of VNC are you using?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 UltraVNC 1.2.1.2

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions here? [How to re-enable aero effects in Windows 7 after it has crashed?](https://superuser.com/questions/28685/how-to-re-enable-aero-effects-in-windows-7-after-it-has-crashed?rq=1)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 none of those worked - only good for W7 I guess...

Comment: While it is not a permanent solution, it might work as a band-aid.  Trying the command `net stop Themes && net start Themes` in Command Prompt.  Let me know if that does anything.

Comment: @CheesusCrust still no success - I do appreciate the suggestions!